# moving a string from one array to another

Tags: c, string

I have to create a program in which a random number is generated, and that number is then assumed as the index of array 'article'. I have to hold the string present at that index in another array, 'hold'. However, this doesnt seem to work. What mistake have I done?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
   char *article[]={"the","a","one","some","any"};
   int x;
   char hold[20];
   x=1+rand()%5;
   article[x]=hold;
   printf("\n%s",hold);
}
```

Comment: One issue is that C (like most programming languages) uses 0-indexed arrays. You don't want to be adding 1 to `x`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is the `1+` for in `x=1+rand()%5;`. If you use `x` as an index to `article`, so it should be between 0 and 4 inclusive. So you should use `x=rand()%5;`.

Then you do `article[x]=hold;` expecting `hold` will contain the selected article. You probably meant `hold=article[x];`.

But you defined `char hold[20];` as if you planned to make a copy there, so you probably meant `hold=strcpy(hold, article[x]);`.

Finally I noticed you put the line break before the line instead of after in `printf("\n%s",hold);`. Dis you mean `printf("%s\n",hold);`?

For your information, the whole `main()`function can be rewritten like this:

```
   char *article[]={"the","a","one","some","any"};
   printf("%s\n",article[rand()%5]);
```

but it's easier read if you keep the seperate steps like you did.

Comment: I would recommend modifying your answer not to have everything in the `printf`. This is messy, harder to read, and generally not a good coding practice. The compiler will likely optimize away any intermediate variable anyways.